# Kerberos 5 Application Server

Tags: kerberos

I'm have installed krb5-appl-server and krb5-workstation; also config the krb5.conf in /etc/krb5.conf in KDC server
I have created a user root/admin in KDC
But when i'm on application server, type :
`kadmin -p root/admin`
they say : "missing parameters in krb5.conf required for kadmin client while initializing kadmin interface"
What's missing in krb5.conf ???
In krb5.conf in application :

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = test.com   
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true

[realms]
 EXAMPLE.COM = {
  kdc = 10.85.0.20:88
  admin_server = 10.85.0.20:749
 }

[domain_realm]
server.test.com = test.com
client.test.com = test.com
```

Tks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing is that case matters in realm names so test.com and TEST.COM are not the same realm. Secondly, you don't have an admin server defined for the default realm in your krb5.conf

```
default_realm = test.com
```

The default_realm should match at least one realm in the realm section and should be the same as the realm name you used in setting up the server.

Answer (score 0):

`missing parameters in krb5.conf required for kadmin client while initializing kadmin interface` is very misleading.
I was met with same mistake and found the error had nothing to do with the `krb5.conf`. Maybe the errror lies in your command line. In my case, I sent a wrong realm name to `-r parameter`.When I set it right, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

**

```
[realms]
 EXAMPLE.COM = {
  kdc = 10.85.0.20:88
  admin_server = 10.85.0.20:749
 }
```

**

I believe you should've replaced the EXAMPLE.COM with TEST.COM